# fsck still going 24 hours later

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, fsck

I have a 1TB NVMe with Ubuntu (~300GB used). Using a live USB + GParted, I resized the root partition to 400GB.

When I rebooted I got the error "File system check of the root filesystem failed. The root filesystem on /dev/... requires a manual fsck" (something like that, I don't remember exactly). So I ran `fsck -fy /dev/...` and it's been going for a full day now.

Right now it's doing tons of these: "Unattached inode ####. Connect to /lost+found?", but earlier it was something with deduplicating blocks that were used by multiple inodes or something.

Does anyone know what's happening? Did I do something wrong? How long could this conceivably take for 300GB of data? Is it possible to safely interrupt it?

Comment: Is that still a new partition? Because if so you could just stop everything and reformat. That being said, if it really gives you errors, that would mean the drive has physical problems and if that's what is happening, it could explain why it's so slow (i.e. it tries to read/write sectors and is not able to, try again, again...)

Comment: No, it's a partition with data on it. It's not giving errors, I think. Just those weird messages that I don't know what they mean.

Comment: The inode messages mean that it found what look like part of a file, but it's not attached to (part of) any file. The only other reason I can think of would be a really slow drive. 300Gb is not that much for fsck. 10Tb like I have starts to be quite a chunk though. :-)

Comment: Have you checked the health of your drive?   I'd have checked that out first (before your `fsck`) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: **It means that your disk is totally corrupt**. `fsck` should only take a minute or two to run. Cancel it. Do you also have Windows on this computer? If so, did you install a Windows driver that allows you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions?

Comment: Ok, cancelled (hard reboot because Ctrl+C does nothing). I should have expected that. I booted to a live USB and mounted the partition. Nothing shows up in the home folder, and a lot of other folders are empty (e.g. /snap). Weirdly enough the partition is still the full 1TB. So, I lost everything then?